# How to deal with "Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.intellij'. Gradle IntelliJ Plugin requires Gradle X.X and higher" error

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

My plugin is based on official Jet Brains template, however Java one, not Kotlin.

When I opened my project, I got the error

> An exception occurred applying plugin request [id:
> 'org.jetbrains.intellij', version: '1.12.0']
> Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.intellij'.
> Gradle IntelliJ Plugin requires Gradle 7.3 and higher

The dependencies in build.gradle.kts are

```
plugins {
    // Java support
    id("java")
    // Kotlin support
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.10"
    // gradle-intellij-plugin - read more: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.12.0"
    // gradle-changelog-plugin - read more: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-changelog-plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.changelog") version "1.3.0"
    // detekt linter - read more: https://detekt.github.io/detekt/gradle.html
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.17.1"
    // ktlint linter - read more: https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.0.0"
}
```

Would you please no teach me how to deal with this error? I understand that I need to update the Grade, however how to do it with IntelliJ IDEA for current project?

My Project configuration is:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.intellij', version: '1.12.0'] Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.intellij'. Gradle IntelliJ Plugin requires Gradle 7.3 and higher

Please open the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, and check what version is there.
You could change the old Gradle version to any version new than 7.3 in that file's `distributionUrl` part to fix this problem and click the Gradle reload button to reload this project.

Or run something like `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 8.0` from the command line to update the Gradle version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have understood how to act in the similar situations. Unfortunately I have got another error related with breaking changes, but I'll consider it in [the other topics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75490926/4818123).