# "Val cannot be reassigned" error has occurred after update the Gradle from 7.2 to 7.3

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA plugin is based on official Jet Brains template, however Java one, not Kotlin.

Solving the error [Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.intellij'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75479185/how-to-deal-with-failed-to-apply-plugin-org-jetbrains-intellij-gradle-intell/75480192#75480192), I have updated the Gradle from **7.2** to **7.3**. Then, trying to build the project, I have got the error

> Val cannot be reassigned

(I'll append the detailed output in the end of this question).

I have checked the [Gradle 5.0 causes error Val cannot be reassigned when using Kotlin DSL in buid.gradle.kts](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1265) issue on GitHub. There, the cause was the `classDirectories` field which hase become read-only. But when I have tried to search the `classDirectories` in my projet, there was not the search results.

Maybe the solution will be obvious for advanced Gradle users, but Gradle/Java/Kotlin is not my specialization while I need to create the plugins for IntelliJ IDEA.

### Appendix

#### Output with stack trace

```
11:58:14: Executing 'buildPlugin --stacktrace'...


> Configure project :
[gradle-intellij-plugin :] Gradle IntelliJ Plugin is outdated: 1.12.0. Update `org.jetbrains.intellij` to: 1.13.0
e: D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\YamatoDaiwaES_Extensions\IDEsPlugins\IntelliJ_IDEA\build.gradle.kts:49:5: Val cannot be reassigned
e: D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\YamatoDaiwaES_Extensions\IDEsPlugins\IntelliJ_IDEA\build.gradle.kts:49:15: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Property<String> was expected
e: D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\YamatoDaiwaES_Extensions\IDEsPlugins\IntelliJ_IDEA\build.gradle.kts:50:5: Val cannot be reassigned
e: D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\YamatoDaiwaES_Extensions\IDEsPlugins\IntelliJ_IDEA\build.gradle.kts:50:14: Type mismatch: inferred type is List<???> but ListProperty<String> was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\YamatoDaiwaES_Extensions\IDEsPlugins\IntelliJ_IDEA\build.gradle.kts' line: 49

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 49:     version = properties("pluginVersion")
               ^ Val cannot be reassigned

  Line 49:     version = properties("pluginVersion")
                         ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Property<String> was expected

  Line 50:     groups = emptyList()
               ^ Val cannot be reassigned

  Line 50:     groups = emptyList()
                        ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is List<???> but ListProperty<String> was expected

4 errors

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
ScriptCompilationException(errors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Val cannot be reassigned, location=C:\Users\Takeshi Tokugawa\.gradle\.tmp\gradle-kotlin-dsl-2962856697602439688.tmp\build.gradle.kts (49:5)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Property<String> was expected, location=C:\Users\Takeshi Tokugawa\.gradle\.tmp\gradle-kotlin-dsl-2962856697602439688.tmp\build.gradle.kts (49:15)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Val cannot be reassigned, location=C:\Users\Takeshi Tokugawa\.gradle\.tmp\gradle-kotlin-dsl-2962856697602439688.tmp\build.gradle.kts (50:5)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Type mismatch: inferred type is List<???> but ListProperty<String> was expected, location=C:\Users\Takeshi Tokugawa\.gradle\.tmp\gradle-kotlin-dsl-2962856697602439688.tmp\build.gradle.kts (50:14))])
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptModuleTo(KotlinCompiler.kt:187)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptToDirectory(KotlinCompiler.kt:148)
    // ...


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
11:58:15: Execution finished 'buildPlugin --stacktrace'.
```

#### build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt
import org.jetbrains.changelog.markdownToHTML
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

fun properties(key: String) = project.findProperty(key).toString()

plugins {
    // Java support
    id("java")
    // Kotlin support
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.10"
    // gradle-intellij-plugin - read more: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.12.0"
    // gradle-changelog-plugin - read more: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-changelog-plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.changelog") version "1.3.0"
    // detekt linter - read more: https://detekt.github.io/detekt/gradle.html
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.17.1"
    // ktlint linter - read more: https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.0.0"
}

group = properties("pluginGroup")
version = properties("pluginVersion")

// Configure project's dependencies
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    detektPlugins("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:1.17.1")
}

// Configure gradle-intellij-plugin plugin.
// Read more: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin
intellij {
    pluginName.set(properties("pluginName"))
    version.set(properties("platformVersion"))
    type.set(properties("platformType"))
    downloadSources.set(properties("platformDownloadSources").toBoolean())
    updateSinceUntilBuild.set(true)

    // Plugin Dependencies. Uses `platformPlugins` property from the gradle.properties file.
    plugins.set(properties("platformPlugins").split(',').map(String::trim).filter(String::isNotEmpty))
}

// Configure gradle-changelog-plugin plugin.
// Read more: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-changelog-plugin
changelog {
    version = properties("pluginVersion")
    groups = emptyList()
}

// Configure detekt plugin.
// Read more: https://detekt.github.io/detekt/kotlindsl.html
detekt {
    config = files("./detekt-config.yml")
    buildUponDefaultConfig = true

    reports {
        html.enabled = false
        xml.enabled = false
        txt.enabled = false
    }
}

tasks {
    // Set the compatibility versions to 1.8
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    withType<Detekt> {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    patchPluginXml {
        version.set(properties("pluginVersion"))
        sinceBuild.set(properties("pluginSinceBuild"))
        untilBuild.set(properties("pluginUntilBuild"))

        // Extract the <!-- Plugin description --> section from README.md and provide for the plugin's manifest
        pluginDescription.set(
            File(projectDir, "README.md").readText().lines().run {
                val start = "<!-- Plugin description -->"
                val end = "<!-- Plugin description end -->"

                if (!containsAll(listOf(start, end))) {
                    throw GradleException("Plugin description section not found in README.md:\n$start ... $end")
                }
                subList(indexOf(start) + 1, indexOf(end))
            }.joinToString("\n").run { markdownToHTML(this) }
        )

        // Get the latest available change notes from the changelog file
        changeNotes.set(provider { changelog.getLatest().toHTML() })
    }

    runPluginVerifier {
        ideVersions.set(properties("pluginVerifierIdeVersions").split(',').map(String::trim).filter(String::isNotEmpty))
    }

    publishPlugin {
        dependsOn("patchChangelog")
        token.set(System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN"))
        // pluginVersion is based on the SemVer (https://semver.org) and supports pre-release labels, like 2.1.7-alpha.3
        // Specify pre-release label to publish the plugin in a custom Release Channel automatically. Read more:
        // https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/deployment.html#specifying-a-release-channel
        channels.set(listOf(properties("pluginVersion").split('-').getOrElse(1) { "default" }.split('.').first()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Note [the usage guide](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-changelog-plugin#usage). You should be using `version.set(properties("pluginVersion"))` and `groups.set(emptyList())` (both in the `changelog` block).